# Upload a video to Youtube using the python API and set it as unlisted

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm using the [python client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to upload videos to youtube.

I need to the set it's privacy as unlisted, but the [API page](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python.html) only shows examples of how to set them as private.

Anyone knows how to change the privacy control of these videos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML element that you need is described in http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl

Following the API documentation, you can build this element as follows:

```
from gdata.media import YOUTUBE_NAMESPACE
from atom import ExtensionElement

# set video as unlisted
kwargs = {
    "namespace": YOUTUBE_NAMESPACE,
    "attributes": {'action': 'list', 'permission': 'denied'},
}
extension = ([ExtensionElement('accessControl', **kwargs)])

# create the gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry
video_entry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(media=my_media_group,
    geo=where, extension_elements=extension)
```